# Conditions for an AWS IAM Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I've created an IAM role with a condition below. I want to give access if any of my three condition met. Because there is no way three of them will be met. Is this the right way to do so?

```
{
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "AWS": "*"
                    },
                    "Action": "*",
                    "Condition": {
                        "StringEquals": {
                            "a": "b",
                            "c": "d",
                            "x": "y"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
          }
```

Any tips on this will be appreciated thanks!

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html is the doc

Comment: I'm sorry actually I found that one as well, but I didn't get it much :(

Answer (score 2):

[This documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html) outlines how things work:

> If your policy has multiple condition operators or multiple keys
> attached to a single condition operator, the conditions are evaluated
> using a logical AND. If a single condition operator includes multiple
> values for one key, that condition operator is evaluated using a
> logical OR. All conditions must resolve to true to trigger the desired
> Allow or Deny effect.

In your example, you have a single condition operator--`StringEquals`.  That condition operator has multiple keys--`a`, `c`, and `x`.  So your current example would be evaluated using logical AND, which does not sounds like what you want because it would require that all three conditions be met, which you said will never happen.

To allow access as you describe, I believe you would need to make 3 separate statements.  Each statement would have a single condition operator `StringEquals` and that operator would have a single key.  Then, if the user met any of the conditions in the 3 statements, the user would get access as you desire:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "a": "b"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "c": "d"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "x": "y"
                }
            }
        }       
    ]
}
```